# Where do I find the name of the windows version of this golang image?

Tags: docker, go, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Here is an excerpt from my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: golang:1.9.2

variables:
  BIN_NAME: example
  ARTIFACTS_DIR: artifacts
  GO_PROJECT: example
  GOPATH: /go 

before_script:
  - mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}
  - mkdir -p ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${ARTIFACTS_DIR}
  - go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
  - cp -r ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/* ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}/
  - cd ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}
```

This is for Linux. I need a Windows image that is configured for golang.

I tried the following:

```
image: golang:1.12.6-windowsservercore
```

The above is documented on docker hub.
But I get this error:

> ERROR: Preparation failed: Error: No such image:
>   golang:1.12.6-windowsservercore (executor_docker.go:182:0s) Will be
>   retried in 3s ...

Please note that I am aware the `before_script` will not work with this image but it should at least find the image.

Answer (score 1):

The image you are trying to pull does exist on dockerhub, but as stated in the [golang documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang), the `windowsservercore` is only available for gitlab-runner [Docker executors](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) that are running on Windows containers. The gitlab-runner that you are using is most likely a Docker executor running on a Linux machine.

You need to register a gitlab-runner in a Windows container with the Docker executor in order to be able to use the image `golang:1.12.6-windowsservercore`.